# 404 Error on files in the same directory

Tags: html, css, flask

I have this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "style.css"/>
```

in `index.html` and my file structure is:

[image]

Where `index.html` and `style.css` are in the same folder.

But when access the page I get:

```
10.240.0.231 - - [06/Jul/2018 22:26:13] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

(I'm running a flask server and accessing the page through that if that matters)

Comment: Check some flask doc about the static files, you can follow this pattern for example : http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/organizing.html#single-module

Comment: thanks so much! Adding a static folder fixed it!